# What is the "python priority library"?

Tags: python

I'm assessing if the project I'm working on is affected by a list of CVEs, including [CVE-2016-6580](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2016-6580).

The vulnerability is, that...

> A HTTP/2 implementation built using any version of the Python priority
>   library prior to version 1.2.0 could be targeted by a malicious peer
>   by having that peer assign priority information for every possible
>   HTTP/2 stream ID. The priority tree would happily continue to store
>   the priority information for each stream, and would therefore allocate
>   unbounded amounts of memory. Attempting to actually use a tree like
>   this would also cause extremely high CPU usage to maintain the tree.

What is the "Python Priority Library"? I duckduckgo'd it, but that project seems to be completely unknown except for being mentioned in that specific CVE.

Has anyone some more information on this?

Comment: Your link text says CVE-2016-6301 but links to CVE-2016-6580.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CVE refers to the Python Hyper module, an HTTP2 client for python, more specifically the **priority** sub-module.

This is the Git pull request associated to the vunlerability:

> https://github.com/python-hyper/priority/pull/23

This is the report in which the problem was addressed:

> http://www.imperva.com/docs/Imperva_HII_HTTP2.pdf